# Checking $_GET value with Other value - not working

Tags: php, get

I want to show something if $_GET value is not equal to any of below values,

We know we should use OR operator for this, but its not working.

however, Its working with AND operator

But its not unusual behaviour.

```
if( $_GET['product_tag'] != 'download' || $_GET['product_tag'] != 'download free' ){
     echo 'hello world';
}
```

I also tried another way also:

```
if( $_GET['product_tag'] !== 'download' || $_GET['product_tag'] !== 'download free' ){
    echo 'hello world';
}
```

but same.

Comment: If `$_GET['product_tag']` is 'download', then it is not equal to 'download free', so the second part is true. If `$_GET['product_tag']` is set and is not 'download', then the first part is true. To implement "none of the values in a list", try `array_search`.

Comment: Your first condition will always be true. The != means doesn't equal. In order to satisfy the first criteria to be true, the variable needs to not be set to download. So any value other than download makes it true. But say it's false, meaning the value is download. Then the second criteria will be  true since download != download free. Since the condition is || meaning OR, since at least one of the criteria is true, the result is always true. You should instead reach for && as an AND condition when working with != does not equal.

Comment: "We know" we should use AND operator for this

Comment: "however, Its working with AND operator" if you already know how to get it working, what's the problem?

Comment: but 'download' and 'download free' are two different categories, as per my knowledge If we want to check for either of condition to be true... then we should OR operator. How can these both condition could be true at the same time..... on either of these category page?

Comment: OR's and AND's need to be swapped with each other when moving from equals comparison to not equals comparison. If it's too confusing for you, you can instead use an if/else like so: `if( $_GET['product_tag'] == 'download' || $_GET['product_tag'] == 'download free' ){ echo ''; /* product tag is download or download free*/}else{
    echo 'hello world';/* product tag is something else */
}`

Comment: Ultimater bro! "OR's and AND's need to be swapped with each other when moving from equals comparison to not equals comparison." Such a golden rule for me. :D I will remember this hook line you gave me ....hehehe thank you :). By the way, will this be always true in all not equal to scenerios ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use AND operator.
Here is your code:

```
if( $_GET['product_tag'] != 'download' && $_GET['product_tag'] != 'download free' ){
     echo 'hello world';
}
```